# Future builder(future:) is recursing my http requests,

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to fetch data from three different url before page rendering. So,
this is the method inside my ScopedModel includes multiple http.post methods:

```
Future fetchData() async {
  _isLoading = true;
  notifyListeners();
  await fetchAvailable();
  await fetchOnProgress();
  await fetchCompleted();
  _isLoading = false;
  notifyListeners();
```

}

The methods inside of fetchData area just classic http.post request with raw Future type.

This is my FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: model.fetchData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
              ? Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Column.......
```

The problem is, the 'future' function, it's executes constantly and never ends. My algorithm about, fetching the json from server, inflates the variables within body into ListView.builder descendants.

The output is as I said recursive post requests. Also, I'm getting this logs, the number of lines increments like 1 - 2 - 3 or 2 - 4 - 6 -8 etc.

```
uid=10085(my.package.directory) 1.ui identical 1 lines
.......Other logs here
uid=10085(my.package.directory) 1.ui identical 3 lines
```

And goes on like that...

Also, is there any other useful way to handle that small amount of data before page rendering?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Edman ok, I'm making the question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not make HTTP requests in `FutureBuilder`

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
>   State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or
>   State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
>   State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
>   FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
>   FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
>   the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Comment: Here I created initState like this:

    @override
      void initState() {
        MainModel model = ScopedModel.of(context);
        model.fetchData();
        super.initState();
      }

But it's not working, same recursive acting...

Comment: Ensure that `fetchData()` doesn't fetch again if the data was already fetched previously, for example by caching the data.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!, I shifted down the requests to a single one and the usages of model.fetchData() are just initState and FutureBuilder, nothing more, but still recursing...

Comment: Did you check how often `initState()` is called? If a parent is rebuilt it might cause a child being rebuilt and the state being recreated. My suggestion is to do such stuff entirely outside the widgets and only notify the widgets about state changes to re-render (for example using scoped model).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your suggestions tomorrow and will report the results. I think the builders are the problem.

Comment: Again, thank you Gunter!
I've handled it, moved all the data process into the ScopedModel. Also, there were some minor nested data types errors and the widget type now is StatelessWidget. For FutureBuilder users, I suggest they better go with snapshot for using fetched data instead of fields.

Comment: I didn't understand the fix. Could you please post your updated answer as before and after for completion here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible right solution. This makes your data load just one time inside scaffold. First make sure you are using stateful widget.

Define your data:

```
Future<List<Data>> futureList;
```

Make a function to fetch your data from backend:

```
Future<void> getList() async {
    final provider = Provider.of<DataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final list = provider.getData();
    setState((){
      futureList = list;
    });
  }
```

Load your function in init state:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      getList();
    });
  }
```

Call your fetched data in future builder:

```
Widget _body(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: futureList,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if(snapshot.data.length == 0){
            return Center(child: Text('List is empty'));
          }else {
            return ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                      child: DataItem(
                        index: index,
                        dataClass: snapshot.data[index],
                      ),
                      onTap: () {});
                },
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length);
          }
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
```